# extracting JSON data from an anonymous function with puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

The webpage I'm scraping has following content:

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <span id="an_id">
      <script type="text/javascript">

var foo = "";

$(function(){$('#bar').something(
  {
    data: [
      { title: 'x', description:'x_desc' },
      { title: 'y', description:'y_desc' }
    ],
    whatever: 1
  });}
);
      </script>
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to get the data in the array, so I'm interested in this:

```js
[
  { title: 'x', description:'x_desc' },
  { title: 'y', description:'y_desc' }
]
```

I've been trying with `page.evaluate()` and `page.queryObjects()`, but to no avail, I just don't understand it well enough.

Anyone who could point me in the right direction?

**Edit:**

I hacked it together like this, but it's so nasty that it makes me want to throw up:

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('file://C:/tmp/test.htm');

await page.waitForSelector("#an_id")

const scriptContents = await page.$eval('#an_id', e => e.innerHTML);

console.log(`scriptContents: ${scriptContents}`)

const startDelimiter = "data:"
const endDelimiter = "whatever: 1"

const startDelimiterIndex = scriptContents.indexOf(startDelimiter) + startDelimiter.length;
const endDelimiterIndex  = scriptContents.indexOf(endDelimiter);
const rawData = scriptContents.substring(startDelimiterIndex, endDelimiterIndex).trim().slice(0, -1);

console.log(`rawData: --${rawData}--`)

const data = eval(rawData);
console.log(`data:`)
console.log(data)

console.log(`the description of y: ${data[1].description}`)

await browser.close();
```

Which produces:

```
scriptContents: 
      <script type="text/javascript">

var foo = "";

$(function(){$('#bar').something(
  {
    data: [
      { title: 'x', description:'x_desc' },
      { title: 'y', description:'y_desc' }
    ],
    whatever: 1
  });}
);
      </script>
    
rawData: --[
      { title: 'x', description:'x_desc' },
      { title: 'y', description:'y_desc' }
    ]--
data:
[ { title: 'x', description: 'x_desc' },
  { title: 'y', description: 'y_desc' } ]
the description of y: y_desc
```

There ***must*** be a better way :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this should do it (untested):

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  let html = document.querySelector('#an_id script').innerHTML
  return html.match(/\[.*\]/s)[0]
})
```

Comment: It's not better/cleaner than my solution, it's just matching anything between the square brackets, which is exactly the same as matching with my startDelimiter and endDelimiter, the only different it's that you're using a regex iso string matching The JSON data is likely to have more square brackets in it in my case (not in the example), that wouldn't work with your solution. This doesn't qualify as a cleaner/better solution to me, sorry :)